# Change column sizes by clicking - Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I need your help again.

I want to change the column size by clicking a button.

Like from this:
[image]

To this:
[image]

With the following code(from stackoverflow) it's possible to change **one** colummn size. I want to change at least **two**.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
     Some content
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
 $('.glyphicon-menu-hamburger').click(function() {
$(this)
    // Find parent with the class that starts with "col-md"
    // Change class to "col-md-3"
    .closest('[class^="col-md"]')
        .toggleClass('col-md-2 col-md-1')
    // Find siblings of parent with similar class criteria
    // - if all siblings are the same, you can use ".siblings()"
    // Change class to "col-md-2"
    .siblings('[class^="col-md"]')
        .removeClass('col-md-1')
        .addClass('col-md-2');});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this:

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  var columns_container = $(".dynamic-columns");
  if (!columns_container.hasClass("expanded")) {
    $(".dynamic-columns .col:first").removeClass("col-xs-2");
    $(".dynamic-columns .col:first").addClass("col-xs-1");
    
    $(".dynamic-columns .col:last-child").removeClass("col-xs-8");
    $(".dynamic-columns .col:last-child").addClass("col-xs-9");
    columns_container.toggleClass("expanded");
  }
  else {
    $(".dynamic-columns .col:first").removeClass("col-xs-1");
    $(".dynamic-columns .col:first").addClass("col-xs-2");
    
    $(".dynamic-columns .col:last-child").removeClass("col-xs-9");
    $(".dynamic-columns .col:last-child").addClass("col-xs-8");
    columns_container.toggleClass("expanded");
  }
});
```

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  z-index: 10;
}

h4 {
  text-align: center;  
}

.main-container {
  margin-top: 50px; 
}

.col {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid main-container">
      <div class="row dynamic-columns">
        <button>Toggle</button>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col">
          <h4>First Column</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col">
          <h4>Second Column</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col">
          <h4>Third column</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Way

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
$(this).parents('.row').find('.first-block').toggleClass('col-md-2 col-md-1');
$(this).parents('.row').find('.last-block').toggleClass('col-md-8 col-md-9');
})
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2 first-block">
<a href="#" class="btn btn-blue">Click</a>
Col-MD-2
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
Col-MD-2
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 last-block">
Col-MD-8
</div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tk89ufpy/1/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.changeColSize').click(function(){
   var parent = $(this).parent('div');
   $(parent).removeClass('col-xs-2').addClass('col-xs-1');

   $(parent).siblings( ".col-xs-8").removeClass('col-xs-8').addClass('col-xs-9');
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Column Change</title>

 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-2">
    <button class="btn btn-success changeColSize">click</button>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-2">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-8">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

This is Html code inside the body.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <button class="btn btn-success changeColSize">Change Col Size</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is jQuery function to change the columns.

```
$('.changeColSize').click(function(){
    //get the parent of button
    var parent = $(this).parent('div');
    //change the parent
    $(parent).removeClass('col-md-2').addClass('col-md-1');
    //change the sibling
    $(parent).siblings( ".col-md-8").removeClass('col-md-8')
             .addClass('col-md-9');
});
```

Hope This will help you.

Comment: When "click" button again, the column dont restore its previous size. I would edit the answer to add a toogle line

Answer (score 0):

Now i want to remove 1 column with all entrys .
If i use:

`$(".dynamic-columns .col:first").removeClass("col-xs-2");
    $(".dynamic-columns .col:first").addClass("col-xs-0");`

...it dosent work.